# textbox_leave event fires twice when click on combobox

Tags: c#, mouseevent

Hi
I have used textBox_leave method in order to validate the textbox and if the mouse is clicked on any control I want to show a message box. My code is something like shown below.

```
private void txtbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

 if(textbox.Text != "this")
  {
 messagebox.show("Not valid");
 textbox.focus();

  }

}
```

The issue is when I click on a comboBox in the form the messagebox pop up twice. If I click on any other control it works fine. 
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It would be more appropriate to use [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged or ComboBox.SelectedValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_events.aspx) to validate the value selected by the user from the comboBox.

Comment: I want to validate the textbox value..  message box must be shown if there is not valid text in text box when we click on combobox or other control.Not only the combobox.For other controls it works fine. The issue is when accessing combo box.

Comment: Maybe you could check if the textbox has some valid text on private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) { txtbox_Leave(sender, e); } in case of the combobox

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce.  Maybe try this:

```
string message = (sender is Control) ? ((Control)sender).Name : "";
message += " " + sender.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

See what is triggering the event.